# Dialogflow entity automated expansion

Tags: dialogflow-es

In Dialogflow, what is the best way of "training an entity" that is set to be automated by expansion. Is there any difference between adding the entity in training phrases and simply adding example values in the entitiy screen? Does the Dialogflow training take one into more consideration than the other? It is required that you add at least one value when creating an entity.

So should I just add one value and then add the rest as highlights in training phrases for a given intent? Or should I add as many values as possible when creating the entity.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Automated expansion is used when a user input matches an intent but the entity value doesn't exist yet. See a detailed explanation in [the documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities/create-manage-entities#allow_automated_expansion).

Example:

- Entity color [blue, green]
- Intent *"My favorite color is [color]"*

User says *"My favorite color is yellow"* - it matches the intent and the color is added to the entity.

But what if the intent isn't exactly the same?

User says *"I like the color blue"* - knows that blue is part of the color entity so might be matched.

User says *"I like the color yellow"* - the phrase doesn't match the intent and the color isn't in the entity - probably not matched.

Having a lot of examples in your entity helps match an intent, even if the phrasing is a bit off. Having a lot of training phrases helps match an unknown entity value.

Ideally, you have both a lot of training phrases and a lot of entity values to help recognition. Hope this makes sense.

[keep in mind that these examples are just for illustration]

Comment: Fantastic explanation! Just out of curiosity, how do you know this? Is there some documentation that you've read somewhere that is this specific? It seems like Dialogflow is a bit of a black box when it comes to how the machine learning and algorithms work. Thanks again!

Comment: I do work for Google (see my profile). But the information is publicly available. Check out this page https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities/create-manage-entities#allow_automated_expansion that describes the process really well.

Comment: How does this work with ambiguous entity values? For example, if there was a "names" entity, there could be multiple spellings of Jon/John/etc? And if these are being mapped to database values contextual to the user, how would this be handled?

Comment: My advice would be to have just one value - John - with a synonym - Jon - and in your webhook kick off a disambiguation step ("Hey, John, did we spell your name correctly?" yes/no, then spell the name). Compare it to being on the phone with someone who tells you their name. If you're not sure, you might ask how they spell it, right?